# the "trail" in LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: java

When i pay attention to the method of unlink in LinkedBlockingQueue first time ,i think that the second parameter of trail means that it's next Node of the first parameter-p,but i was wrong, because i found in the method of remove(Object o),it means that trail node is the pre Node than p, so i pay attention back to the method - unlink , and found the comment says - 'Unlinks interior Node p with predecessor trail.' ,  it makes me wonder that why the author named the pre Node 'trail',isn't it means the next node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code of [jdk7](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java), it's called `trail`:

```
void unlink(Node<E> p, Node<E> trail)
```

And it has been changed to `pred`

```
void unlink(Node<E> p, Node<E> pred)
```

in jdk 10:

```
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

Comment: thanks , I used jdk1.8.0_111 , seems that they fixed it later.